# Series representation for $\log(|\zeta(\frac{1}{2}+it)|)$

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, real-analysis, analytic-number-theory, sequences-and-series, riemann-zeta-function

(Question is short and straight-forward. )

> > What is/are "nice and non-trivial" series representation/s of $\log(|\zeta(\frac{1}{2}+it)|)$ ??

By "nice and non-trivial" I mean contains no more than double sum and no direct Taylor expansion

Comment: Something tells me that you want to use it for "Balazard, Saias, and Yor's equivalence to the Riemann Hypothesis"

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**: 
you might start with wely Bound which is defined as :$t\in\mathbb{R}$, then $|\zeta(\frac{1}{2}+it)|\leq c(|t|+1)^{1/6}$ this means that $\log|\zeta(\frac{1}{2}+it)|\leq \frac16 \log(c|t|+1)$, you can easly deduce the representation series of $\log(c|t|+1)$ which  it is defined as :
$\log(c|t|+1)=\log(c|t|)-\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1^k)}{k c^k|t|^k},|ct|>1$,And if you want really to find such non trivial series representation of $\zeta(0.5+i t)$ in general  , you may look to find such polynomial of degree N using local trigonometric approximation I recomond you to check [this nice post](https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2019/05/03/local-trigonometric-polynomial-approximations-to-the-riemann-zeta-function/)  by Terence Tao

Comment: This is awesome! Can you give a source for that first bound, though? And can you explain what is $c$ in that bound?